# need webbrowser width in the css definition to calculate the width of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to calculate with the width of the browser screen and other data the width of a div called incontent in the file index.php. I heard that I can use java script to get the screen width. But the main problem is that the style definition is described in an external stylesheet file called style.css. So I don t know if it's possible to use the java script variable in the stylesheet definiton. I don't want to work with css media queries... Can somebody suggest how to solve this problem? Greets

Comment: See [ask] and [Stack Overflow Question Checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: "But the main problem is that the style definition is described in an external stylesheet file called style.css. So I don t know if it's possible to use the java script variable in the stylesheet definiton.", You've got that the wrong way around, you should be thinking about how to access the value which is in the style sheet from JavaScript. And that's not a problem at all as the DOM will hold the value after the page is rendered according to the stylesheet, which can then be altered. See the other comments and answers to this question which point to jQuery as a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to do it with Javascript or CSS media queries. Since you mentioned you don't want to do media queries, I suppose you'll have to write the appropriate Javascript to do it.

Unfortunately (or maybe fortunately) you can't access any Javascript variables within your CSS files, and CSS doesn't have any sort of functionality; it's simply for styling.

With that said, I don't know why you are avoiding media queries, but that is the appropriate way to handle a responsive design, or else you can use percentages.

Comment: but the css media queries is not supported in every webbrowser thats why I don't want to use media queries...

Comment: IE 9+, Firefox 3.5+, Chrome 4+, Safari 4+, Opera 9.5+, and every mobile browser support them. It's really good support. http://caniuse.com/css-mediaqueries

Comment: Yes I know but i need it also for IE 9 >

Answer (score 0):

You can get the width of the screen with:

```
var documentWidth = document.body.clientWidth
```

and assign it to whatever element with:

```
document.getElementById('id_of_the_elemen').style.width = documentWidth
```

I don't know if this answers your question, I'm no sure I got it right

Answer (score -1):

If you want to use Javascript, you might want to consider JQuery.

You can get the screen width by using [**width()**](http://api.jquery.com/width/):

```
$(window).width();
```

If you want to get the width of a div, there is [**innerWidth()**](http://api.jquery.com/innerWidth/), to get the inner width (between the padding).

```
$("div#divId").innerWidth();
```

Or [**outerWidth()**](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/) to get the width including padding and border (and margin, check example).

```
$("div#divId").outerWidth(); /* without margin */
$("div#divId").outerWidth(true); /* with margin */
```

You may also want to check these helpfull links:

- http://www.google.nl/search?q=jquery+window+width
- http://www.google.nl/search?q=jquery+div+inner+width
- http://www.google.nl/search?q=jquery+div+outer+width

Comment: no. Three links to google do not count as answer. Maybe as a comment, but not as an answer

Comment: I've updated my answer with examples.

Comment: still not a good answer, I'm afraid. The asker has in no way indicated he'd be using (or willing to use) jQuery, and jQuery is not exactly helpful here either. Please do note that the javascript tag explicitly states that „unless a library tag is also included, a pure-javascript solution is expected.”